# Make mockito throw exception in case the stub is not defined

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to understand if I can do the following in mockito.

Let's say I have this class:

```
class PersonService {
    public NameResolver resolver;

    public String getFullName(Person person) {
        // ...
        String firstName = resolver.getFirstName(person);
        // ...
        String lastName = resolver.getLastName(person);
        // ...       
        return firstName + lastName;
    }
}
```

And have a test for this class:

```
class PersonServiceTest {
    private PersonService underTest;

    @Test
    void test() {
        NameResolver mock = mock(NameResolver.class);
        PersonService underTest = new PersonService(mock);

        when(mock.getFirstName()).thenReturn("first-name");

        underTest.getFullName();
    }
}
```

The thing is, that I have unstabbed `resolver.getLastName(person)` method and mockito will stub this with default value (`""` in case of `String`, I guess). What I'd like to do is to throw exception every time I call method of the mock that no stub attached. There is a framework named `mockk` in Kotlin ecosystem which behaves like this and this feature makes you write really reliable unit tests and it is pretty convinient after all.

I saw `Answers` class in mockito and it looks like this behaviour is configurable but I spend pretty much time looking for an answer on the web and suprisingly found nothing.

Moreover I saw that I can make mockito throw exceptions in case there are mocks that are not in use, but didn't found if I can make this option a default one, like via config file or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Create the mock [with a default answer](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.11.2/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock-java.lang.Class-org.mockito.stubbing.Answer-):

```
NameResolver mock =
    mock(
        NameResolver.class,
        invocation -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); });
```

This answer will only be invoked for otherwise-unstubbed methods.

Comment: Thank you, I saw this solutions, but this will add a huge amount of boilerplate to unit tests.So you aware of a way to make this a default behaviour?

Comment: I doubt you can make it the default behavior (and I suggest that would be undesirable, as it would also affect places outside your code which are relying on the existing default behavior); but you can either store this `Answer` in a static field and reference it in all your `mock` invocations, or you can write a method like `throwingMock(Class<T> clazz)` which wraps the call above, and use that instead of `mock(Class<T>)` where you require it.

Comment: Well, at least it is something. I will see if there is some more ideas and most likely accept your answer in some time cause it really looks like a thing that can't be configured globally. Thank you very much for your time!